# Could someone please help me understand this question?

Tags: arithmetic

I was given this question today as part of a technical analysis, which I failed to answer. I am not sure what is expected?

Is it really just a case of substituting the values at the bottom in place of ...? It seems unlikely. Can someone please explain the question to me?

```
1. Add up the numbers in the following series

17 + 34 + 51 + … + 71,417


a) 150047117
b) 170047117
c) 130047117
d) 160047117
e) 190047117
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$17(1 + 2 \ldots 4201) = 17 (4201)(4202)/2 = 150047117$$

Note: It is making use of Gauss's formula for the sum of the 4201 numbers.

**Approach**

- You can see that there is a common factor of $17$ in the increasing number.
- You can now factor (divide) the last number by $17$ and it gives $4201$.
- Now, you need a formula to sum the first $4201$ numbers.
- Thanks to Gauss, we have the sum of the first $n$ numbers as $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about the theory and the steps you took to get to the answer?

Comment: That's awesome, thank you.

Comment: You are very welcome. Note that one of the main branches of math is the search for pattern and sometimes when working problems, see if you cand find a pattern or modify the problem to expose a pattern! Glad I could help. Regards

Comment: Nicely done, and nice feedback, too! +1

Comment: The "crowd" here at MSE is getting to be a difficult crowd to please lately!

Answer (score 2):

The problem wants you to add up all the multiples of $17$ from $17\cdot1$ to $17\cdot4201=71,417$.  If you're a Gauss, you can see in an instant how to do this.  If you're not a Gauss, you might still realize that the sum must also be a multiple of $17$.  You might also notice that at most one of the offered answers can be a multiple of $17$, since they differ from one another by small multiples of $10,000,000$, which is not divisible by $17$.  So it suffices to see which one $17$ actually divides.

My pocket calculator won't allow $9$-digit numbers, which stymied me at first, until I noticed the $17$ at the end of each number.  So instead of looking at $150047117/17$, for example, it suffices to look at $1500471/17$.  Etc.  As soon as you get an integer quotient, you're done.

Comment: There's a little bit of subtlety in the fact that if $150047100$ is a multiple of $17$ then $1500471$ is (certainly this doesn't work so well if you choose, say $25$ instead of $17$!)